# 12.04: 2 defined users but one with mute sound at login

Tags: 12.04, gnome, sound

Ubuntu 12.04 64 bits
Gnome-shell 3.4.1

I have defined 2 users: one with administration rights and another standard.
With the user with admin rights there isn't problem but when the other user enters in his gnome session it has the sound muted:
[image: sound menu]

But the gnome-alsa-mixer shows all normal:

[image: gnome-alsa-mixer]

If he move the volume slider the sound is unmuted.
What could be the problem?

Comment: Are you running Pulseaudio?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the second user is not in the audio group. Login as the admin user and open a terminal. Type:

```
            id [non-admin user name here]
```

which will show group memberships of the non-admin user. If it's not in the audio group, you should add it to this group using:

```
            sudo usermod -aG audio [user name here]
```

Insert the user name without the square brackets. This could do the trick.

Comment: It depends on our sound setup. In default Ubuntu users should **not** be in the *audio* group. http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/PerfectSetup

Comment: This isn't the solution. To the no-admin user works the sound, the problem is when he login in its gnome session the sound are always muted.